# Getting an index from an array pulled from Parse.com - fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode-6.2

I'm fairly new to `Swift` and I've been trying to pull individual items from an array stored in `Parse.com`

When printing the array itself, I get all the users, however, when attempting to get the first index of an array I get the following error

> "fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer"

This is code I'm currently using -

```
import UIKit
import Parse
class feedTableViewController: UITableViewController {
  var titles = [String]()
  var usernames = [String]()
  var images = [UIImage]()
  var imageFiles = [PFFile]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //....
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var myCell:cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as cell
    //Error occurs here - does not work due to empty buffer
    myCell.title.text = titles[indexPath.row]
    myCell.username.text = usernames[indexPath.row]
    //If the previous two lines are commented out, I can print out both the arrays
    println(titles)
    println(usernames)

    return myCell
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please reduce your code to [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also specify on which line the error you quoted occurs.

Comment: @AaronBrager I have reduced the code and narrowed down to where the error is displayed on xCode. Though I would've thought that the removed code may have helped others understand the code better? Thanks

Comment: Does `println(titles[indexPath.row])` print what you expect? `titles` may be empty, or may have fewer elements than you return in `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: @AaronBrager No it doesn't. It gives me the same error when printed out. However, I currently feel like crying. numberOfRowsInSection was the culprit. It wasn't calling the number of items of the array, rather a set number. Thanks Aaron. Much appreciated. You have NO idea how long I've spent trying to fix this.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the number of elements in `titles` matches the number you return in `numberOfRowsInSection`.